# Is there a way to use a TV as a monitor, but have it act as a 2x2 grid of monitors?

Tags: screen, software, display

I'm looking into a multiple monitor setup, but I have a spare TV I'm not using. My only concern is that I want to be able to make an app full screen without taking up the whole TV.

Is it possible to map different portions of one screen to be treated as 4 separate screens?

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what kind of equipment you have and the types of connections available to you with both of them.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then the closest you can get with El Capitan is two full screen apps on one screen. You can not have four virtual desktops on one screen though.